# Camlquery with date comparison

Tags: caml-query

Cannot get this to Work, it returns all rows.
Anyone?

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name='Modified'/>
      <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>2015-06-30T17:27:13Z</Value>
    </Geq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: It's looks OK. Could we see the rest of the code?

Comment: If you are using server side code then try removing the <Query> element. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms456030(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: have you tried the same in caml query builder. what is the sp version.